# Call function with multiple DOM element references

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a script (external to the React project itself) that takes in one or more DOM element references as input.

Inside a React FC I need to be able to call this script and pass it the multiple DOM node references when the user clicks a button.

In other times that I needed to use DOM references I would use Callback Refs in the manner described in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node). But this is only good for when you only need one DOM ref and use it as soon as it is available (instead of at an arbitrary time later on).

In this case however, **I need to be able to reference multiple (ready) DOM nodes and pass them to a function in response to an onClick event in another element**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions62823009-vvi2s?file=/src/App.js

You can actually save refs and use them later at any point.